# Visual Studio, C#, проблема подсказок

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем привет, есть небольшая проблема в Visual Studio 2019. 
Появились странные подсказки, которые мешают писать стандартный код
Если нажимаю на иконку [+] то на данной строке подсказки становятся стандартными, как только перехожу на новую строку снова включается иконка[+]. Переустановка не помогла. Заранее премного благодарен (я новичок, извиняюсь за свою терминологию если она не правильна)
( Стандартные подсказки второй скрин)

[image: Подсказки]
[image: Стандартные подсказки]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Откройте окно настроек:

`Tools -> Options` (`Средства -> настройки` или `опции` не знаю как в русской версии это меню называется)

Уберите галку:

`Text Editor -> C# -> Intellisense -> Show items from unimported namespaces (experimental).`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

p.s. рекомендую поставить англ. версию студии